# What did we learn about the fate of the Love Actually characters from the Comic Relief special?

Tags: love-actually

One of the special features of 2017's *Comic Relief* telethon was a film about the fate of the characters of *Love Actually*, 14 years on from the original film.

What had happened to the characters?

Comment: http://www.express.co.uk/showbiz/tv-radio/783684/Love-Actually-sequel-Red-Nose-Day-2017-Hugh-Grant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much that they were all in wonderful relationships with the people they started relationships with.

In short, a 10 minute Happy-Ending update

FAR too much went on to describe here, but there is an in depth summary here:
[Radio Times Summary](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2017-03-25/red-nose-day-actually-recap-what-happened-to-hugh-grant-bill-nighy-and-the-rest-of-the-love-actually-cast)

Comment: To make this a more informative answer, perhaps you could list each character, and their fates?

Comment: If I come have a bulleted list summarizing the content of the article character by character then this would be a great answer.  Come on, you know you want to!